# Apache2 ModSecurity2 does not work (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, mod-security2

I followed the official documentation at [wiki.ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Apache/mod_security) but my test.php file still allows malicous access, like test.php?secret_file=my/secret/file.txt. Ideas why?

test.php:

```
<?php
    $secret_file = $_GET['secret_file'];
    include ( $secret_file);
?>
```

The expected result of test.php?secret_file=my/secret/file.txt is HTTP 403 -access denied, but my web server still shows the contents of the included file.

My installation steps:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-security2
sudo a2enmod security2
sudo a2enmod headers

Configuration

sudo cp /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf-recommended /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf

# Enable ModSecurity, attaching it to every transaction. Use detection
# only to start with, because that minimises the chances of post-installation
# disruption.
#
#SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly
#
SecRuleEngine On                                   

Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/*.conf
Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/*.conf
Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/*.conf

SecDebugLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_debug.log
SecDebugLogLevel 5

sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service apache2 force-reload
```

Here is my modsec_debug.log file: [modsec_debug.log](http://www.file-upload.net/download-10203046/modsec_debug.log.html)

When I call the malicious test.php?secret_file=my/secret/file.txt it says:

```
[Sun Jan 25 13:21:51.773188 2015] [:error] [pid 14993] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "eq 1" against "&ARGS:CSRF_TOKEN" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf"] [line "31"] [id "981143"] [msg "CSRF Attack Detected - Missing CSRF Token."] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "VMTf31XWGY4AADqRE00AAAAB"]

[Sun Jan 25 13:21:51.777069 2015] [:error] [pid 14993] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Warning. Operator LT matched 5 at TX:inbound_anomaly_score. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_60_correlation.conf"] [line "33"] [id "981203"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score (Total Inbound Score: 3, SQLi=0, XSS=0): Request from Known SPAM Source (Previous RBL Match)"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "VMTf31XWGY4AADqRE00AAAAB"]

[Sun Jan 25 13:21:51.777133 2015] [:error] [pid 14993] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx (?i:(<meta.*?(content|value)=\\"text/html;\\\\s?charset=|<\\\\?xml.*?encoding=))" against "RESPONSE_BODY" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "23"] [id "981220"] [msg "[Watcher Check] No charset was specified in the HTTP Content-Type header nor the HTML content's meta tag."] [data "Content-Type Response Header: text/html"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "APP_DEFECT/MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag "http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Content_handling_mechanisms"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "VMTf31XWGY4AADqRE00AAAAB"]

[Sun Jan 25 13:21:51.777193 2015] [:error] [pid 14993] [client x.x.x.x] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx (<meta.*?(content|value)=\\"text/html;\\\\s?charset=utf-8|<\\\\?xml.*?encoding=\\"utf-8\\")" against "RESPONSE_BODY" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/modsecurity_crs_55_application_defects.conf"] [line "36"] [id "981222"] [msg "[Watcher Check]  The charset specified was not utf-8 in the HTTP Content-Type header nor the HTML content's meta tag."] [data "Content-Type Response Header: text/html"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "MISCONFIGURATION"] [tag "http://websecuritytool.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Checks#charset-not-utf8"] [hostname "example.com"] [uri "/test.php"] [unique_id "VMTf31XWGY4AADqRE00AAAAB"]
```

Comment: Is there any rule which would tell mod_security that "my/secret/file.txt" is a secret file?

Comment: I do not think so because I only have the default rules from installation. How do I set this rule?

Comment: Whats the use case of `secret_file` query in your `test.php` file? Can you post the contents of `test.php`?

Comment: I added the content for test.php in the header of my post. The use case is to deny access to file.txt (-> HTTP 403 -access denied).

Answer (score 0):

The rules at modsecurity_crs_43_csrf_protection.conf is looking a CSRF attack, however, the one you are trying to execute is not CSRF.

You could try this,

1. Remove Include `/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/*.conf` and `Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/optional_rules/*.conf` from your `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf` (I guess you are using Ubuntu).
2. Create a ruleset in `/etc/modsecurity/modsecurity_crs_15_customrules.conf`
3. Include this rule in that file `SecRule REQUEST_URI "secret" "phase:1,t:none,log,deny,id:'9000070001',msg:'Malicious content blocked'"`
4. Run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Try to hit the same URL from your browser, watch the /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log and let me know how it goes.

Thanks,

Daniel